# deselect NSCollectionViewItem by clicking on it

Tags: xcode, cocoa, flowlayout, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

How can I deselect a NSCollectionViewItem by clicking on it again?

This is the code I use for selecting and deselecting:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, didSelectItemsAtIndexPaths indexPaths: Set<NSIndexPath>) {
        print("selected")
        guard let indexPath = indexPaths.first else {return}
        print("selected 2")
        guard let item = collectionView.itemAtIndexPath(indexPath) else {return}
        print("selected 3")
        (item as! CollectionViewItem).setHighlight(true)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, didDeselectItemsAtIndexPaths indexPaths: Set<NSIndexPath>) {
        print("deselect")
        guard let indexPath = indexPaths.first else {return}
        print("deselect 2")
        guard let item = collectionView.itemAtIndexPath(indexPath) else {return}
        print("deselect 3")
        (item as! CollectionViewItem).setHighlight(false)
    }

/////////////////////

    class CollectionViewItem: NSCollectionViewItem {


        func setHighlight(selected: Bool) {

            print("high")
            view.layer?.borderWidth = selected ? 5.0 : 0.0
            view.layer?.backgroundColor = selected ? NSColor.redColor().CGColor : NSColor(calibratedRed: 204.0/255, green: 207.0/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1).CGColor
        }
    }
```

This code deslect when another item is clicked, but not when the same item is. I want to deselct when the same item is clicked.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by observing the selected state on the item, and installing an `NSClickGestureRecognizer` on the item's view when it's selected, and uninstalling it when it is deselected.

Put the following code somewhere in your `NSCollectionViewItem` subclass:

```
- (void)onClick:(NSGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (self.selected) {
        //here you can deselect this specific item, this just deselects all
        [self.collectionView deselectAll:nil];
    }
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected {
    [super setSelected:selected];
    if (selected) {
        [self installGestureRecognizer];
    }
    else {
        [self uninstallGestureRecognizer];
    }
}

- (void)installGestureRecognizer {
    [self uninstallGestureRecognizer];

    self.clickGestureRecognizer = [[NSClickGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                            action:@selector(onClick:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.clickGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)uninstallGestureRecognizer {
    [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:self.clickGestureRecognizer];
    self.clickGestureRecognizer = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy trick is to use CMD - Left mouse click. Although this doesn't solve my problem exactly, it is still better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Thank [Marko Hlebar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/652049/marko-hlebar) for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48539253/1260976).

Based on this, I realized the function of clicking the item to switch its selection.

```
class MyItem: NSCollectionViewItem {
    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            self.view.layer?.backgroundColor = (isSelected ? NSColor.blue : NSColor.gray).cgColor
            // If the selection causes the size to change, re-layout.
            self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(NSClickGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onClick(sender:))))
    }

    @objc private func onClick(sender: NSGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let indexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPath(for: self) else { return }
        if self.isSelected {
            self.collectionView?.deselectItems(at: [indexPath])
        } else {
            self.collectionView?.selectItems(at: [indexPath], scrollPosition: [])
        }
    }
}
```